# gsutil ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050]

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to get `gsutil` working on my machine, and it always fails with the following error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:358: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

There are a lot of posts about this error for other python applications, where the solution involves editing the source code. If the source code is the problem then the `gsutil` developers need to know about it, yet they don't advertise how a user would post a bug.

I may have made a mistake installing `gsutil`. Maybe I need get a certificate and set it up? But I have not idea how to do this.

I did manage to get around this by disabling server authentication in the `.boto` file. However for security I would prefer to have authentication working.

Hoping there are some people out there who could help me with this problem.

Comment: You can post gsutil bugs to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues
Can you please provide the output of running gsutil -d <whatever command>. Please strip out authorization headers. If you want to avoid posting it on the public forum please send to gs-team@google.com.

Answer (score 2):

Partial update will fix the problem

**Method 1**
If you use gsutil source then

Update only httplib2 package
https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2

Or

update only certificate inside httplib2 package
https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/blob/master/python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt

**Method 2**

specify system certificate to boto.xt file
https://github.com/fout/fout/blob/master/review/google_snippet_status/templates/boto.xt

```
https_validate_certificates = True
ca_certificates_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

ref: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html

**NOTE: **
In my case:
If I use system like "ca_certificates_file = system" it gives some socket error

```
    Caught socket error, retrying: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:330: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
Retrying request to url <https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/adx-rtb-freakout-vd/o?   projection=full&prettyPrint=True&versions=False&fields=prefixes%2CnextPageToken%2Citems%2Fname&prefix=snippet_status&maxResults=500&delimiter=%2F&alt=json> after  connection break.
Caught socket error, retrying: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:330: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Retrying request to url https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/adx-rtb-freakout-vd/o?projection=full&prettyPrint=True&versions=False&fields=prefixes%2CnextPageToken%2Citems%2Fname&prefix=snippet_status&maxResults=500&delimiter=%2F&alt=json after connection break.

***NOTE:***  Best is using latest gsutil and Python 2.7.X

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem on my Linux box today when I was writing a web application. For what its worth, here is my solution:

```
chmod a+r /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/cacerts.txt
```